# iOs values to PHP script - BAD_EXC_ACCES

Tags: php, ios, post, exc-bad-access

i can't send my values to my php file.
My app pauses, because there is a thread at the send connect

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}





         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoursite.nl/locatie.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                          timeoutInterval:60];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"longitude=%@&latitude=%@&stringFromDate=%@", longitude, latitude, stringFromDate];

    NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    [theRequest setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];




    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        [responseData appendData:data];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        [responseData release];
        [connection release];
        [textView setString:@"Unable to fetch data"];
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData
                                                       length]);
        NSString *txt = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

    }

    }
```

My PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php

 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
  $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
  $timestamp = $_POST['stringFromDate'];

  $con = mysql_connect('db.server.nl', 'user', 'pass');
  if (!$con)
  {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

  mysql_select_db("db", $con);

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp)
   VALUES ('06', 'longitude','latitude','timestamp')");

 mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually create and send the connection, and indicate where within that code it crashed?

Comment: I thought this was the part where the create the connection. I followed this guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html. In the top of this topic i told you where it crashes.

Comment: JSON or XML? The php script is not returning any message, HTTP response code?

Comment: @DavidRaijmakers You must have forgotten to post the code where you instantiate the `NSURLConnection`. I also don't quite understand what you mean by "there is a thread at the send connect" and if that's indeed where you were getting the crash. If you could update your question to include the relevant code and a clear description of what crashed and any other details it would be easier to help you.

Comment: No the problem is not that it doesn't return anything. Not that it does. But my app is crashing at that point... I also don't get anything in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code....

```
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"log=%@&pwd=%@",strUserName,strPassword];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"",[postData length]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ideaact.neonexusdemo.com/wp-content/themes/idea/andr.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

Comment: you check my edit code it is successfully worked... try this ... i hope it is help you.. Thank you